# Is it possible to mark a potentially uninitialized variable as good without using unsafe or panicking?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to explain to the compiler that the `v` variable is good at the line marked as `1` without using unsafe or code that may call `panic!`?

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Enum {
    V1,
    V2,
    V3,
}

fn main() {
    let e = Enum::V1;

    let mut v: i32;

    if e == Enum::V1 || e == Enum::V2 {
        v = 17; //some complex, costy expression
    }
    match e {
        Enum::V1 | Enum::V2 => {
            println!("Results: {}", v); //1
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

The compiler reports:

```
error[E0381]: use of possibly uninitialized variable: `v`
  --> src/main.rs:18:37
   |
18 |             println!("Results: {}", v); //1
   |                                     ^ use of possibly uninitialized `v`
```

I have a complex expression to initialize `v` in my real code instead of `17`, the type of `v` does not implement `Default`, and I only need `v` for the `Enum::V1` and `Enum::V2` cases.

In the real code I have separate branches for `Enum::V1` and `Enum::V2`, and I can move `v` initialization there.

I want to make my code more clear and I don't want to use potentially bad things like `unsafe` or `Option::unwrap`

Answer (score 6):

The simple method is to initialize `v`; it's a single word and the compiler can probably optimize it away if it is unnecessary. In this particular case, you could even move both the declaration and initialization into the inner scope of the match, because it isn't used anywhere else.

The cleaner thing to do is to make the invalid case unrepresentable. Here `v` only really exists in the cases `V1` or `V2`, so if we join the two we don't have a name for a possibly uninitialized value.

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Enum {
    V1 { v: i32 },
    V2 { v: i32 },
    V3
}

fn main() {
    let mut e = Enum::V1 { v: 17 };

    match e {
        Enum::V1 {v} | Enum::V2 {v} => {
            println!("Results: {}", v);//1
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

This is how types like [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) and [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) function.

Comment: It seems that this answer doesn't really address the underlying problem. Putting the value `v` in the enum still requires that `v` be computed at *some* point, but doesn't show how to only compute it for the two required cases. This answer would make more sense *after* the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45371311/155423) has been used. [Two enums: one like the OP and used in the other answer, and one like this answer's](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=9df5e679dc814d8eefb94e840c7694b3&version=stable).

Answer (score 5):

In safe Rust, you cannot. In your code, `v` is only guaranteed to be initialized under the conditional branch `e == Enum::V1 || e == Enum::V2`, and yet `v` was declared in a wider scope. Note that this is not a limitation, but a hint from the compiler that the design of the program should be reconsidered.

In this case, I would delegate the calculation of `v` to a function and only have `v` in the necessary case blocks.

```
fn calculate_v(e: Enum) -> i32 { ... }

let e = Enum::V1;

match e {
    Enum::V1 => {
        let v = calculate_v(e);
        // use v
        println!("Results: {}", v);//1
    }
    Enum::V2 => {
        let v = calculate_v(e);
        println!("Results: {}", v);//1
    }
    _ => {}
}
```