# Why do I not get an error about a use of possibly-uninitialized value in one match, but not in another match that uses `panic`?

Tags: rust

```
const FILE_NAME: &str = "/tmp/main.rs";

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let metadata;
    match std::fs::metadata(FILE_NAME) {
        Ok(meta_data) => {
            metadata = meta_data;
            println!("metadata: {:?}", metadata);
        }
        _ => {
            panic!("not meta enough!");
        }
    }

    let modified: std::time::SystemTime;
    match metadata.modified() {
        Ok(x) => {
            modified = x;
            println!("modified: {:?}", modified); // this works
        }
        _ => (),
    }

    // println!("modified: {:?}", modified); //-> this does not work
    let len = metadata.len();
    println!("metadata: {:?}", metadata);
    println!("len: {}", len);
}
```

I don't understand why it fails if I uncomment line 22:

```
error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `modified`
  --> src/main.rs:25:32
   |
25 |     println!("modified: {:?}", modified); //-> this does not work
   |                                ^^^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `modified`
```

The same code on line 18 works ok. What am I overlooking?

Comment: because in one case you init the value, in the other you didn't

Comment: I don't see how this could be more clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to mark a potentially uninitialized variable as good without using unsafe or panicking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45371062/is-it-possible-to-mark-a-potentially-uninitialized-variable-as-good-without-usin)

Comment: "But same line at 18 works Ok. What am I overlooking? " ah, but you used `panic!("not meta enough!");` the compiler is smart enough to conclude `metadata` is init after the match because otherwise your would have panic. and in your second part you don't panic so `modified` could be not init after the match

Comment: thanks, I understand the magic now. can you add this as an answer, so I mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the problematic line, Rust cannot be sure that `modified` was actually initialized.

An alternative would be to have an early return if `modified` cannot be set:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let metadata;
    match std::fs::metadata("dsf") {
        Ok(meta_data) => {
            metadata = meta_data;
            println!("metadata: {:?}", metadata);
        }
        _ => {
            panic!("not meta enough!");
        }
    }

    let modified: std::time::SystemTime = match metadata.modified() {
        Ok(x) => {
            println!("modified is set to {:?}", x); // this works
            x
        }
        _ => return, // early return on error
    };

    println!("modified: {:?}", modified);
    let len = metadata.len();
    println!("metadata: {:?}", metadata);
    println!("len: {}", len);
}
```